# Match any string before end of a character

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a date which returns either "23-12-2010" or '2013-'
I want to extract the valid year for 2013- ie. 2013 and valid date for 23-12-1010 i.e 23-12-2010. 
So I am trying to extract all the tring before last '-' if it is present.

I tried like below.

```
"2013-"[/.+?(?=-)/]
```

But it returned only "23-12" for the date "23-12-2010"
What am I missing here.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 p "23-12-2010".chomp('-') # => "23-12-2010"
 p '2013-'.chomp('-')      # => "2013"
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like in your case the year contains 4 digit, so you can write something like:

```
2.1.5 :037 > "23-12-2010"[/\d{4}/]
 => "2010"
```

As you can see this regexp will detect year by 4 digits pattern.

Comment: I want to return the 23-12-2010 for the above date. and for 2010- i want to return valid year i.e. 2010

Answer (score 0):

Its not good solution but i think it will work for you:

```
s="23-12-2010"
s.split('-').size==3 ? s.split('-').last : s.split('-').first
=> "2010"

s2="2010-"
s2.split('-').size==3 ? s2.split('-').last : s2.split('-').first
=> "2010"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sub to remove the dash at the end:

```
"2013-".sub(/-\z/, "")
=> "2013" 

"23-12-2010".sub(/-\z/, "")
=> "23-12-2010"
```